# Proving translations in R and rotations in C are groups under composition

Tags: abstract-algebra

a). Prove that all the translations of the plane $R^2$ form a group under composition of functions (use vectors to write your proof).

b). Prove that all rotations of $C$ around a fixed point A form a group under composition of functions (use complex numbers to solve the problem).

For a) I have that if I let $u =<a,b>, v =<c,d>, w =<e,f> \in R^2$ and $(x,y) \in R^2$

Closure: $T_u \circ T_v (x,y) = (x+a+c, y+b+d) \in R^2$

Associative: Composition of functions is associative. I showed this to be true in an earlier problem.

Identity: If I let $e = <0,0>$ then $T_u \circ T_e (x,y) = T_u$ which implies that $T_e$ is the identity element.

Inverse: If I let $u =<a,b> , v =<-a,-b> $ then $T_u \circ T_v  (x,y)= T_v \circ T_u (x,y) = T_e (x,y) = (x,y)$. So then $T_v = T_u ^ {-1}$.

So a) is true.

I'm having trouble showing that this is true for b). So far I have that if I let $P_{\theta}(z) = e^{i \theta}z$ and $v=a+bi$, then the rotation is $P(z) = e^{i \theta} z + v(1-e^{i \theta})$. So I have to show closure, associativity, that an identity exists, and an inverse exists. I am having trouble showing this is true under composition.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The [identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) is so named because it is the identity element under composition of functions. You should make sure it is present both in (a) and (b). As for solving (b), concentrate on rotations around $0$ first, and prove that they form a group. It's easier, and the result can be used to prove the general case more easily.

Comment: Hint: consider rotation through $- \theta$

Comment: @BrianO That's what I'm doing but I'm confused as to if I should be using a composition of two different, general rotations say, $P_{\theta _1} (P_{\theta _2} (z))$.

Comment: You'll want to show that rotation through $\theta_2$ and then $\theta_1$ equals rotation through $\theta_1 + \theta_2$.

Comment: @BrianO Ok. That is what I figured. So then I assume I would not need to do anything to $v$ as $T_v$ is just a translation that moves $z$ to the origin to do the rotation and then moves it back with $T_{-v}$?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes. Sticking to rotations about $0$, what's puzzling? $P_{\theta_1}(P_{\theta_2}(z)) = e^{i \theta_1} e^{i \theta_2} z =  = e^{i (\theta_1 + \theta_2)} z$, so... . Associativity under composition follows from associativity of complex multiplication (also used to derive the identity just shown).

Comment: @BrianO Yes. That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate the plane through an angle $\theta$ around a point $A$ you translate the plane by $-A$, rotate by $\theta$ and then translate by $A$ to put the plane back to where it was.

Thus, $r_{\theta}(z) = e^{i\theta}(z-A)+A$

Now,

$r_{\phi}(r_{\theta}(z)) = r_{\phi}(e^{i\theta}(z-A)+A) = e^{i\phi}((e^{i\theta}(z-A)+A)-A)+A= e^{i\phi}(e^{i\theta}(z-A))+A=e^{i(\phi+\theta)}(z-A)+A=r_{\phi + \theta}(z)$

Associativity follows by considering both $r_{\theta_1 + \theta_2}(r_{\theta_3}(z))$ and $r_{\theta_1}(r_{\theta_2 + \theta_3}(z))$.

$r_0$ serves as the identity and $r_{-\theta}$ is the inverse of $r_{\theta}$